# How to map from a generic type to a non-generic type?

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a source type:

```
public class Foo<T>() {}
```

where `T` is always an enum.

And I have a destination type:

```
public class Bar() 
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Firstly, I want to map only from `Foo` to `Bar`, and on mapping, I want to set the type name too.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do I get that right, that you want `Bar.Type` to be `T.GetType().Name` after the mapping?

Comment: @Fildor Correct. But I only want just mapping configuration.

Comment: Like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MAzEkt ?

Comment: If there are more than a few other properties that match, then a generic resolver for `Type` fits better than a type conveter.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Both classes have some other matching properties. Is there an example I can follow?

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/UnitTests/OpenGenerics.cs#L203